# How can I return a validation rule depending on the response status of the request (ReactJS/AntDesign)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, antd, rules

I would like to know how I can return a validation rule depending on the response of a request.

I have an input which, when the user finishes writing, performs a GET where it obtains if the user who is trying to enter already exists, it is like an automatic search that is performing the input. But now what I want to do is that depending on the status of the request return the validation rule

Do you know how I could do something like that?

Currently I return it in an alert message but I would like to return it as I am mentioning them

```
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} style={{ marginBottom: "-44px" }}>
                    {getFieldDecorator(`userName`, {
                      initialValue: selectedData_.userName
                        ? selectedData_.userName
                        : "",
                      rules: [
                        {
                          pattern: new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_.-]+$"),
                          message: <div className="alertsUserName"><IntlMessages id="message.link.pattern" /></div>
                        },
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: <div className="alertsUserName"><IntlMessages id="error.required" /></div>
                        },
                        {
                          // Rule that returns the RES of the API
                          message: <div className="alertsUserName"><IntlMessages id="message.link400" /></div>
                        }
                      ]
                    })(<Input name="userName" className="inputLink" onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur} onKeyDown={(e) => { e.persist(); this.update(e); }}
                      placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
                        id: `maintenace.link.suffixIntructions`
                      })} />)}
                  </FormItem>


//Method

debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let debounceTimer;
    return function () {
      const context = this;
      const args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
      debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
    };
  };

  update = this.debounce(async function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(this.state.value);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/dynamicLink/${e.target.value}/findAffiliate`);
      console.log(response);
      const selectData_ = this.state.form
      // this.setState({ userName: e.target.value });
      this.setState({ ...selectData_, userName: e.target.value })
      console.log(this.state.value);

    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        messages.error(this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "message.link400" }));
      }
      if (error.response.status === 404) {
        messages.error(this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "message.userNull" }));
      }
    }
  }, 3000);
```

[image]

Comment: As I understand, user enter a url and after enter that you get a response. Based on that response state you want to show a custom validation message. Is it?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is. How can I do that?

Comment: can you put a demo of what you done up to now in codesandbox and share it? it will be easy to look into the exact issue.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for answering me. I managed to solve this problem, later I will post the solution of how I did it